# Why do I get Request Method "GET" instead of "POST"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I have started using the dropzone js library and have a question related to it. Shouldn't the `POST` method be used instead of `GET` when uploading an image, or if so how do I fix that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzoneForm",
    {
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drop file here or search.",
        url: "file_upload.php",
        paramName: "file",
        maxFiles : 5,
        method : "post",
        maxFilesize : 10,
        acceptedFiles : '.jpg, .png, .pdf',
        success: function(response){
            var xhr = response.xhr;

            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                maintainAjaxResponse(xhr.responseText);
                listAllImages();
            } else {
                maintainAjaxResponse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Please share more details. The given request (which is sent to `/upload/uploads`) does not match the given configuration (which should send the requests to `file_upload.php`)

Comment: It seems the upload was done successfully and you were redirected to a success page.. the network tab should tell you if redirects happened in between.

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about that completely. So it turns out that everything is working correctly for me :)

Comment: @Gandalf69 — Feel free to hit delete on the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the Method of HTTP request you can change the ajax call parameters named

`method: "POST or GET"`

so you can change you request method.

Comment: We can see, in the code in the question, that they have already done that. If you read the comments on the question you will also notice that 18 hours ago the OP accepted that they had misinterpreted what they were seeing and didn't have a problem.